# No cell borders in jqGrid subgrid with bootstrap

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid JS - v5.3.0. The main grid is using styleUI:'bootstrap'. The subgrid is created by implementing subGridRowExpanded(). Everything is fine in subgrid except there are no border lines between cells(subgrid labels and content/TDs). Couldn't find a configuration by reading thru docs. Is there an "option" for cell bordering? Thx.

(not able to provide code snippet right now. the configurations used in subgrid are height:100%, colnames: [...], colmodel: [...], datatype: 'local' and data: mylocalvariable. not able to test disabling bootstrap)

Comment: Be  a sure you have loaded the correct JS and CSS files. The subgrid demo with working borders is [here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/bootstrap/hierarchy/two_level/index.html). Additionally to this the correct set is  styleUI:'Bootstrap'  and not styleUI:'bootstrap'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the styleUI should only be applied (as shown in above Tony's demo) at the jqgrid level as $.jgrid.defaults.styleUI = 'Bootstrap'; not as one option on the (main) grid's configuration list as I did. This way, the subgrid should have cell border lines. (Or apply styleUI at both the main grid and subgrig. not tested.) Hope it helps others.